# "No module named..." with certain project structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have the following project structure:

```
MainScript.py
ExampleFolder
├ MainImport.py
└ SecondaryImport.py
```

MainScript.py: `import ExampleFolder.MainImport`
MainImport.py: `Import SecondaryImport`

---

When I try to run `MainImport.py` it gets no errors, but when I try to run `MainScript.py`, I get an import error that says `No module named 'SecondaryImport'`.

My question is simple - is there any way that I can import only `MainImport.py` from `MainScript.py` without getting this error, and importing `SecondaryImport.py`? Thanks in advance!

I have also tried adding a blank file named `__init__.py` to the `ExampleFolder`, but the error still appears. I also read [Python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), but I could not find the problem. Am I missing something? (:

Comment: MainImport.py:`from . Import SecondaryImport`

Comment: @prashantrana In `MainScript.py`, I want to only import and use `MainImport.py`. some of the functions in `MainImport.py` uses `SecondaryImport.py`, and I don't need or want to import `SecondaryImport.py` to `MainScript.py`. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: since in Mainimport.py  is dependent on secondaryimport.py ie in mainimport your are importing the package from secondaryimport, so it become hard to didn't import Mainscript.py unless you refactor code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the statement `import ExampleFolder.SecondaryImport` would work.

If it does, the error might be happening because as mentioned in docs, import statements will usually start searching your main project directory where the python interpreter was called if your module is not in python itself.

Another way would be to use relative import statement like this:
`import .secondaryimport` in order to tell the python interpreter to look in the current directory. Hope this helps!

Taking a look at these links will help, I think (It helped me when I was stuck in a similar problem):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path
https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried adding a blank file named __init__.py to the ExampleFolder

That's the way - you're creating a Python package from a directory that way. And with packages you have got namespace `directory.file` where `file` is a Python file also known as module in Python world.

Then you can do from mainscript.py:

```
from examplefolder import mainimport
```

For importing inside package you may use the following syntax inside mainscript.py:

```
import secondaryimport
```

and use it in that mainscript.py as:

```
sevondaryimport.SomeClass()
```

or you may just do:

```
from secondaryimport import SomeClass
```

and use it like:

```
SomeClass()
```

Btw, use lowercase in all the cases except classes names - only they should have CamelCase names.

Comment: In `MainScript.py`, I want to only import and use `MainImport.py`. some of the functions in `MainImport.py` uses `SecondaryImport.py`, and I don't need or want to import `SecondaryImport.py` to `MainScript.py`. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: As said, I want that `MainScript.py` will only import `MainImport.py` and use his functions. Some of the functions in `MainImport.py` use functions from `SecondaryImport.py`.